# Dynamic time warping to detect gestures using Kinect Motion Sensor

Tags: processing, kinect, gesture-recognition, openni, dtw

Is there any documentation explaining how should I use DTW (*dynamic time warping*) and with Kinect? I need to record ([as in this demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwZMNMmODJA)) a gesture and later use the recorded gesture to apply a command to `Simple Open-NI`. I've downloaded [KinectSpace code (pde file)](http://code.google.com/p/kineticspace/downloads/detail?name=kineticspace%20ver.%201.1.1.zip&can=2&q=), however, I'm having issues understanding how it is supposed to be working.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping):

```java
    int DTWDistance(char s[1..n], char t[1..m], int w) {
        declare int DTW[0..n, 0..m]
        declare int i, j, cost

        w := max(w, abs(n-m)) // adapt window size (*)

        for i := 0 to n
            for j:= 0 to m
                DTW[i, j] := infinity
        DTW[0, 0] := 0

        for i := 1 to n
            for j := max(1, i-w) to min(m, i+w)
                cost := d(s[i], t[j])
                DTW[i, j] := cost + minimum(DTW[i-1, j  ],    // insertion
                                            DTW[i, j-1],    // deletion
                                            DTW[i-1, j-1])    // match

        return DTW[n, m]
    }
```

1. What is the meaning of `return DTW[n, m]`?
2. Should all the gestures be evaluated during the draw() method call? Can any optimisation be applied here?

Comment: That return most likely means the value of DTW @ n,m. which is an int. as stated in the second line of the pseudocode.

Comment: Well you would most likely call this in a loop. Disclaimer: I know nothing and just learned everything im about to say on that wiki page. This gives you the distance between the two sequences s&t. I'm assuming that one of the two would be your preprogrammed gesture and the other your recorded gesture. Use this function to see how similar they are. Pick a threshold for determining "the same"-ness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementation using Kinect and DTW with Processing.

[gh/jonathansp/KinectRemoteControl](https://github.com/jonathansp/KinectRemoteControl/blob/master/DTW.pde)

Answer (score 1):

amnon.owed just posted this great tutorial at Processing forum. Maybe it can help you:

http://www.creativeapplications.net/processing/kinect-physics-tutorial-for-processing/

here part of **his** [post](http://forum.processing.org/topic/kinect-physics-tutorial-for-creativeapplications-net):

> My latest tutorial for CreativeApplications.net has just gone live.
>   It's about using a Kinect to interact with geometry on your screen.
>   Several Processing libraries are used (SimpleOpenNI, v3ga, Toxiclibs &
>   PBox2D) to achieve this effect. It's a hands on tutorial so the main
>   content is made up of three fully commented code examples. These
>   exampes will also show you how you can turn a silhouette blob into a
>   polygon, which is useful for many things, even besides 2D physics
>   interaction.